# Google Drive API Listing Files with Field Paramter Not Working

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am currently listing some files with the Google Drive API. However, the default list only lists `id`, `name`, and `mimeType`. I know that the `fields` parameter can list more than just the default, but when I put `parents` as a field in the Google API Playground, I get the error of `Invalid field selection parents`. However, when I use `*` in the `fields` parameter, it returns all the fields. Am I doing anything wrong by putting `parents` in the fields parameter? If so, does anyone have any idea how to include the `parents` field as a field in the list results?

Here is my current endpoint, which causes the error:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=parents&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

Thanks!

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your issue, can you provide the sample endpoint including the query parameter for replicating your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike just edited

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your updated question, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=parents&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`, in your situation, when `parents` is directly put to `fields` as follows,

[image]

such error of `Invalid field selection parents` occurs. Because the method of "Files: list" returns the file list which is an array including each file metadata. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) I think that this is the reason of your issue.

#### Solution:

So in this case, please set `files(parents)` instead of `parents`.

#### Note:

- In the case of `files(parents)`, only `parents` is returned. When you want to retrieve `id`, `name`, `mimeType` and `parents`, please use `files(id,name,mimeType,parents)` to `fields`.

#### References:

- [Try this API of "Files: list"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22fields%22%3A%22files(parents)%22%7D)
- [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)

Comment: OMG, u save my day, I get stuck with this error and there's no way I can make it disappear without your answer. These refs should also be added to your answer: [Return specific fields for a file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/fields-parameter) and [The fields parameter's formatting rules](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-fields-parameter)